Bazaars and Bananas
This is part 71 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
The black letters in this grid form a Hitori puzzle. Shade some cells in the grid so that no two unshaded cells in the same row or column contain the same letter. Shaded cells cannot be next to another shaded cell (they can touch at a corner, but not share an edge), and unshaded cells must form one orthogonally connected area.
The blue numbers make up a Choco Banana puzzle. Shade some cells in the grid so that every orthogonally connected area of shaded cells is a rectangular shape, and every orthogonally connected area of unshaded cells is a non-rectangular shape. Each numbered cell indicates the size of the shaded or unshaded area containing that cell. Areas may contain any number of numbered cells, including none.
Today I have visited a lavish green area in the centre of a historic city, surrounded by gardens, mosques, bazaars, and an imperial palace. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Hitori on Penpa+
Choco Banana on Penpa+

Gladys will return in Fjord Explorer.

ANSWER:

 Naqsh-e Jahan Square, Isfahan, Iran

Completed Hitori:




 Some tactics needed here:
 - marking cells between repeat letters as unshaded
 - unshading a cell if, when shaded, isolates an unshaded cell block
 - shading a cell if, when unshaded, is 'seeing', orthogonally, another of the same letter

Completed Choco Banana:

 The 9's and 8's on the top left have to be unshaded, due to shading them needing rectangles, and 3x3's and 2x4's not fitting.
 Then, the next pair of 9's need to be shaded, due to the 8 being unable to get out if they weren't. We can achieve this by creating a 3x3 'chocolate' square. This can go in only two places, and both of them have r4c5 and r5c4 shaded.
 If r4c2 was a shaded cell, there'd only be one place to satisfy the 2, which forces the 3x3 shaded square of 9's, and would then trap the 8 with no place to fill. Therefore, r4c2 is unshaded.
 The 4 in r6c2 cannot be shaded, because it will extend downwards and then combine the 4 and the 5 together in a region, which is invalid.
 r5c2 must be unshaded, as if it was shaded, the 3x3 square would be forced into the top-right, trapping the 8 without enough filling space. (I'm beginning to feel like this is a recurring theme.)
 Now the 8 can't go down, so it must go right. Finally, the 3x3 square is resolved in the bottom-left!
 We can then unshade all cells orthogonally adjacent to that square. Whew!
 We can then put shading on r7c2 and r7c6 to make sure that the region numbers don't interfere with each other.
 The 9 is very limited now; we can extend the 9 on the top until we get to the 3's and 4's (the 8 region blocks the 9's region from going down) where we get stuck.
 This means that the 9 extends downward one space, and we can then satisfy both the 2 and 4 region.
 From there, it's relatively smooth sailing. Starting from the top right 3, it has one place to go. Shading further, we can't overflow the 8's region, so we shade the 3 region and have it go down.
 Now, the 8 region is satisfied, and we can lock it. The 6 is now shaded, and it must be a 2x3, going from r7c6 to r9c7.
 Now, the 5 can be unshaded in, turning the 4 into a 2x2 shaded square, and the chocolate can't be broken, so we can easily unshade everything other than that on the bottom left, except for r9c1, to prevent a banana square.
 Finally, we can add in some trivial details, and we are done!
! 

Solution:

 Taking the letters in cells where in both puzzles, they're shaded, gives NAQSHEJAHANSQUARE, or punctuated correctly, Naqsh-e Jahan Square, Isfahan, Iran. Hope you enjoy the open air in the square there, Gladys!


It's generally bad form to do a partial answer so early; unless you have a full answer, please wait a while. Also, answers to [grid-deduction] puzzles should generally explain at least some key deductions.

I see. I firmly apologise for this crucially immature blunder.

...and I formally say sorry to you, Gladys, for making an answer as improper as this. I assure you that I shall get better at making these griddy answers, likely with more polished explanations. Here's to a safe journey!
